# Customize "searching" DataTable Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I want to modify the searching property from DataTable jquery:

In this example : https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter.html
There are several input text fields at the bottom of the DataTable, each of them is a filter for the corresponding column.

What I want to achieve is to take out those input text fields from the DataTable because I would like to build my own form with those input text fields using other layout. (I wish to take advantage of the quick response of the "searching" property for giving more dynamism to my form)

What I think is that this part of code in the example:

```
$('#example tfoot th').each( function () {
    var title = $(this).text();
    $(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder="Search '+title+'" />' );
} );
```

can be replace for my own simple HTML input text fields in other place of the web page:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Search " class="test" />
<input type="text" placeholder="Search " class="test" />
<input type="text" placeholder="Search " class="test" />
<input type="text" placeholder="Search " class="test" />
<input type="text" placeholder="Search " class="test" />
<input type="text" placeholder="Search " class="test" />
<input type="text" placeholder="Search " class="test" />
<input type="text" placeholder="Search " class="test" />
<input type="text" placeholder="Search " class="test" />
<input type="text" placeholder="Search " class="test" />
```

But, what I dont figure out is how to modify this part of the code

```
    table.columns().every( function () {
        var that = this;

        $( 'input', this.footer() ).on( 'keyup change', function () {
            if ( that.search() !== this.value ) {
                that
                    .search( this.value )
                    .draw();
            }
        } );
    } );
```

I tried to use my own input text fields, so I replaced the line :

```
$( 'input', this.footer() ).on( 'keyup change', function () {
```

By :

```
$( 'input.test').on( 'keyup change', function () { alert('inside')
```

After some tests with my own input text fields and debugging with alerts statements, I realized that this function is executing as many times as many input text fiels exists because all of them has the "test" class. But, any way, the "searching" property is not working in this input text fields.

Can you give me tips about the appropiate way to modify this DataTable to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it so that an `input` is connected to a specific column. That is, it will only filter the column that you specify

HTML:

```
<input id="column_3_search" type="text" placeholder="Search " class="test" />
```

JS: 
    var table = $('#example').DataTable();

```
$('#column_3_search').on( 'keyup', function () {
    table
        .columns( 3 )
        .search( this.value )
        .draw();
} );
```

This will allow text typed in your `input` to filter your table based only on the values in column 3.

Comment: Thank you. It is working!. Moreover, one of the fields of my form is a selector and i could put the event over the change method.